# Can't use code generators because of "object reference not set to an instance of..."

Tags: entity-framework-4, t4

What can cause this behaviour?

I'm trying to generate code via ADO.NET EntityObject/Poco/SelfTracking Generator and i get only "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

I can add i'm using EF4 with OracleProvider and previously i've generated code with EdmGen2, but right now i'd like to generate POCO classes from existing .edmx file which was created above existing database.

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018236/exception-during-association-fixup-with-nullable-composite-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used this feature, but you might want to look at the stack trace / inner exception of the exception, it will help you track the exception source so it will easier for users to help.

Or even maybe it's a broken relationship or maybe some line of your patial-class constructors or other functions is throwing this error.

Comment: i can't see exception, just error, If you could tell me how can i debug this template :) i could give more details.

Comment: Does it tell you where the error is, i.e. what file, line etc.? try to double click the error and see if it leads you to the error source.

Comment: There are no additional error's info. I'll try to debug this code-generator-template in my spare time, cos i firstly i have to figure out how to do that :)